# Как подключить компилятор Java к CodeBlocks?

Tags: java, компилятор, codeblocks

В 17 версии CodeBlocks появились шаблоны проектов и файлов на Java (вроде бы в 16-м ещё не было). Но в списке поддерживаемых компиляторов я не нашёл ничего похожего на Java. Там где-то ещё можно задать компилятор? Или, может, нужен какой-нибудь плагин?